# get image button with pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

I want to click on the green plus button with `pywinauto` but I can't get the element.

[image]

I able to get the window with `top_windows = Desktop(backend="uia")['Text File Export']`

But then I see only the ListBox without the buttons that located above

```
top_windows.print_control_identifiers()

Control Identifiers:

Dialog - 'Text File Export'    (L2198, T308, R2817, B1033)
['Dialog', 'Text File ExportDialog', 'Text File Export']
child_window(title="Text File Export", control_type="Window")
   | 
   | Pane - 'Files to export'    (L2206, T337, R2809, B503)
   | ['Pane', 'Files to export', 'Files to exportPane', 'Pane0', 'Pane1']
   | child_window(title="Files to export", auto_id="1578672", control_type="Pane")
   |    | 
   |    | ListBox - ''    (L2223, T380, R2792, B490)
   |    | ['ListBox', 'ListBox0', 'ListBox1']
   |    | child_window(auto_id="466446", control_type="List")
   |
   | Pane - 'File format'    (L2203, T509, R2806, B959)
   | ['Pane2', 'File formatPane', 'File format']
   | child_window(title="File format", auto_id="599282", control_type="Pane")
```

Any idea how to click on the plus button?

Thanks!

Comment: try to use uia backend , not win32. Uia provides broader control options.

Comment: FOR UIA BACKEND : Use Inspect.exe , it can provide Automation ID and the exact placement of object in the tree. 

FOR WIN32 : You can use Swapy tool, it is very easy to use and even generates simple code, but it is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `your_variable.print_control_identifiers()` method after assigning the element with `auto_id` `1578672` to a variable named `your_variable`?

Edit:
So you may need to click somewhere for the elements there to be available.

Your can try this.

```
app.Dialog.print_control_identifiers()

panel = app.Dialog.child_window(auto_id="1578672", control_type="Pane").wrapper_object()

panel.click_input()

app.Dialog.print_control_identifiers()
```